# Insert multiple rows with one QUERY

Tags: php, mysql

I had some problems to get information from SELECT sql and then to INSERT that kind of information into my database. The problem is now I cannot solve to insert multiple rows.

I got this, It only insert one item if a category has more items then one it also need to be inserted that amount of times

I get the items in one row now next to each other, but I want those among each other

```
if($log1 = $log->fetch_object())
    {
while($loco = $log->fetch_object())
    {
$item .= "$loco->itemname";
    }
$logss = "INSERT INTO log_drops(`item`, mobname, game, log_id, log_name)VALUES('$item', '$mobname', '$game', '$id', '$name')";
if($result1 = $db->query($logss));
}
```

Comment: `$logss = "INSERT INTO log_drops(item, mobname, game, log_id, log_name) VALUES ";` before the while.... and instead of it in while: `$logss.="('$item', '$mobname', '$game', '$id', '$name'), ";` after the while add `$logss =rtrim($logss ,', ')." ;";` and execute it

Comment: Also I don't want to trim anything because I need to INSERT for exammple 2 items called 'ITEM 1, ITEM 2' but the mobname, game, log_id, log_name are the same I only need to change the `item` row

Answer (score 0):

Create `VALUES` string from the result you are getting. You need to modify little bit as per your requirement. But, below example will give you idea how to do this:

```
$items = '';
while($loco = $log->fetch_object()){
    $items .= '('.$loco->itemname.',';
    $items .= // Some other variables those you want to insert...
    $items .= $loco->xyz.'),';
}
$new_data = rtrim($items, ',');
$clause = "INSERT INTO log_drops(`item`, mobname, game, log_id, log_name)
           VALUES $new_data";
```

Then after you only need to execute only one insert query.

Comment: do you mean with Some other variables like `$game, $mobname` ectra?
And do I need add it each variable each line like: ` $items .= '('.$game.',';`

Comment: You don't need to open bracket for all other variables. basically, we are creating a string, something like this: `(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)`. Output `$new_data` variable and check the format before putting it in `$clause`

Comment: this code will not bring what exactly id needed, variable item will end-up with `comma `

Comment: @fasM that's why, I used `rtrim($items, ',')`

Comment: I get the items now next to each other, I'm really new to this. I edited my start topic

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: @RonakPatel I only get this error: Notice: Undefined variable: item in  that's this line ` $item .= "$loco->itemname";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this style, always i used to get my value out of array and create `sql`

```
<?php
$values = '';  // store values to be inserted
$n=','; // string to manage  comma between chunk of values to be inserted
$numberOfValues=5; // values defind to be inserted
$count = 0;
$recordNum =mysqli_num_rows($log) - 1; //count number of records from 0
while($loco = $log->fetch_object()){
    if($count == $recordNum){ $n = ' '; }
    $values .= "('$loco->itemname','$loco->game','$loco->game','$loco->log_id','$loco->log_name') $n ";
    $count++;
}

$clause = "INSERT INTO log_drops(`item`, mobname, game, log_id, log_name)
           VALUES $values";
?>
```

Comment: Its adding all items in one row, I mean among each other if it's possible. Also i've a question about `$loco->xyz` what does xyz stand for? thank you